# Filling a List with all enum values in Java

Tags: java, list, enums

I would like to fill a list with all possible values of an enum
Since I recently fell in love with `EnumSet`, I leveraged `allOf()`

```
EnumSet<Something> all = EnumSet.allOf( Something.class);
List<Something> list = new ArrayList<>( all.size());
for (Something s : all) {
    list.add( s);
}
return list;
```

**Is there a better way** (as in non obfuscated one liner) to achieve the same result?

Comment: ArrayList<Something> list = new ArrayList<Something>(Arrays.asList(Something.values()))

Answer (score 205, accepted):

I wouldn't use a List in the first places as an EnumSet is more approriate but you can do

```
List<Something> somethingList = Arrays.asList(Something.values());
```

or

```
List<Something> somethingList =
                 new ArrayList<Something>(EnumSet.allOf(Something.class));
```

Comment: Sometimes EnumSet don't cut it. In particular when order matters

Comment: @MonoThreaded What order did you have in mind? An EnumSet is in the natural order for an enum. The list will be in the same order as the set, so using a List doesn't change anything here.

Comment: Sorry, ordering is out of scope for this question. I believe you meant values() in the first example.

Comment: @PeterLawrey we use Enums all the time.  When we design a workflow the approval process may not move in the `Natural Order` of the Enum, this is why a `List<Enum>` comes in handy vs an `EnumSet`.

Comment: `EnumSet` does not have a `get()` method (easy random access) while `List` does. This may be important for whatever the List/EnumSet is intended to be used for

Answer (score 16):

[`Class.getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29)

```
List<SOME_ENUM> enumList = Arrays.asList(SOME_ENUM.class.getEnumConstants());
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a constructor for `ArrayList` which is

```
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

Now, `EnumSet` extends `AbstractCollection` so you can just do

```
ArrayList<Something> all = new ArrayList<Something>(enumSet)
```

Answer (score 10):

try

```
enum E {
    E1, E2, E3
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<E> list = Arrays.asList(E.values());
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: worth clarifying that you do not get a java.util.ArrayList out of this, as stated in the question

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Something> result = new ArrayList<Something>(all);
```

`EnumSet` is a Java Collection, as it implements the `Set` interface:

```
public interface Set<E> extends Collection<E>
```

So anything you can do with a Collection you can do with an `EnumSet`.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is asking about `List` but I think I have possible cleaner solutions as well as one solution using `List` that wasn't added yet.

I'm using `Java 17`

#### Simply use a array of `enum`

```java
public class Main {
    static public enum Something {
        One,
        Two,
        Three,
        Four,
        Five,
        ;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Something[] somethings = Something.values();
        for (Something something: somethings) {
            System.out.printf("- %s\n", something);
        }

    }

}
```

Simple get all values of the enum with `enum.values()`

`Something[] somethings = Something.values();`

##### Use `list.of`

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    static public enum Something {
        One,
        Two,
        Three,
        Four,
        Five,
        ;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        List<Something> somethings2 = List.of(Something.values());
        for (Something something: somethings2) {
            System.out.printf("- %s\n", something);
        }
    }

}
```

I've seen solutions using `Arrays.asList(` which as described in [What is the difference between List.of and Arrays.asList?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46579348/13903942)

> `Arrays.asList` returns a mutable list while the list returned by `List.of` is [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#immutable)

or

> `Arrays.asList` allows null elements while `List.of` doesn't

And few other reasons.
Because theoretically, from an Array of `enum` you should't be able to mutate it (adding / removing elements) I think it makes more sense to use `List.of`
Anyways, it depends by use cases and both ways are probably valid

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more readable:

```
Object[] allValues = all.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
```

Comment: Then you could simply do `Something.class.getEnumConstants()` right?

Comment: ... or `Something.values();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
... = new ArrayList<Something>(EnumSet.allOf(Something.class));
```

as `ArrayList` has a constructor with `Collection<? extends E>`. But use this method only if you really want to use `EnumSet`.

All enums have access to the method `values()`. It returns an array of all enum values:

```
... = Arrays.asList(Something.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also:

```
Collections.singletonList(Something.values())
```

Comment: I am getting hexCode

Answer (score -3):

```
private ComboBox gender;
private enum Selgender{Male,Famle};
ObservableList<Object> observableList  =FXCollections.observableArrayList(Selgender.values());
```