# Why am I needing to replace List.of() with Arrays.asList()?

Tags: java, arrays, dependencies, package, java-11

I've read [What is the difference between List.of and Arrays.asList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579074/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-and-arrays-aslist)

What I'm not getting is why, after some dependency upgrades in my Maven pom.xml, suddenly all my

```
List.of(FLIGHT1_SPEND_AGG, FLIGHT1_IMPRESSIONS_AGG)
```

no longer compile. When I type `List.` in IntelliJ, autocomplete only comes up with the `class` member. I thought maybe I'm not importing `java.util.List`? So explicitly specified it, but still:

[image]

I'm using Java 11, and I see the method exists here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html.

Why can't I seem to use it? I must be doing something stupid...

Comment: Oh, is it because `long` is mutable? But then... how did it compile before? (What change in dependency could have flipped that?)

Comment: Probably because your pom doesn't specify Java 11, and when you reimported for the upgrades it reset the language level in IntelliJ.

Comment: Sometimes IntelliJ causes issues and couldn't find the functions even though the libraries are in the class-path. Maybe try restarting the IDE or clear the IDE cache?

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica - That was exactly it. If you'd like to add your answer as an answer, I can accept yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you defined your Java version in your ide but not in your pom (at least not correctly)

Your pom needs to specify the maven-compiler-plugin and the source and target java versions.

The definition should look similar to this one:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After the updates from maven, your IDE is using the Java version defined in your pom or using the default (which for some versions of the compiler plugin is as old as Java 5), overriding whatever you've set before.