# Refactor function overloaded methods in just one method

Tags: java, overloading

Currently I have a method overloading the following method:

```
    public boolean isHorizontalOrVertical(Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint) {
        return firstPoint.getFirstComponent() == secondPoint.getFirstComponent()
                || firstPoint.getSecondComponent() == secondPoint.getSecondComponent();
    }

    public boolean isHorizontalOrVertical(List<Point> points) {
        if (points == null || points.size() < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid number of points");
        }
        Point start = points.get(0);
        return points.stream()
                .allMatch(p -> isHorizontalOrVertical(start, p));
    }
```

The method is needed to check **if two or three points are vertical/horizontal to each other**. In the case of three points, it just has to check if the two last points are horizontal/vertical to the start point.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get it all into just one method?

Comment: You could use variadic arguments, you could have one function which takes a list?

Comment: Yes, but how would one method look like with the required features?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I would rename your second method, so that you can read it checks if **all** the points in the list are horizontal or vertical. something like: `allPointsAreHorizontalOrVertical`

Comment: What is the advantage of requiring the caller to pass two points as a list? If you don't want to expose the two-point version in a public API, just make the method private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have just one method as follows:

```
public boolean isHorizontalOrVertical(List<Point> points) {
    if (points == null || points.size() < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid number of points");
    }
    if (points.size() == 2) {
       return points.get(0).getFirstComponent() == points.get(1).getFirstComponent()
                || points.get(0).getSecondComponent() == points.get(1).getSecondComponent();
    } 
    Point start = points.get(0);
    return points.stream()
                .allMatch(p -> isHorizontalOrVertical(List.of(start, p)));
}
```

**Note:** If you are not using Java version >= 9, please use [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) instead of [List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-).

Comment: How is `return points.stream()
            .allMatch(p -> isHorizontalOrVertical(start, p));` supposed to work when there is just one method but it needs two arguments?

Comment: What do you mean by `List.of(..)`?

Comment: @EugenCovaci - please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579074/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-and-arrays-aslist

Comment: Are you sure the OP is using Java version >= 9?

Comment: @EugenCovaci - That's the assumption. If it is not the case, OP will comment.

Comment: I am using Java 8

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thank you. Would it be better to use `if (points.isEmpty() || ...)` instead of `if (points == null || ...)`?

Comment: It's not only better rather important to use `points == null` because `points.isEmpty()` will throw `NullPointerException` if `points` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

---

First and foremost I have to note the fact that it doesn't make sense, to me at least, a method which calculates if two entities are **horizontal or vertical** and those entities are **Points**. How can two points be horizontal or vertical?

---

### isHorizontalOrVertical is a bad name

Overcoming the above, you could create a single method which calculates if two points are horizontal or vertical.

Change the name *isHorizontalOrVertical* because it's redundant. A better name is *isHorizontal* or *isVertical*. The method will return a boolean so if isHorizontal returns false, then it's vertical and vice versa. Probably a better name could be *areTwoPointsHorizontal* but I am having trouble even writing that because it transmits the wrong message, but feel free to choose your own.

So the method,

```
    public boolean isHorizontal(Point first, Point second){
        boolean sameFirstComponents = firstPoint.getFirstComponent() == 
                secondPoint.getFirstComponent();
        boolean sameSecondComponents = firstPoint.getSecondComponent() == 
                secondPoint.getSecondComponent();          
        return sameFirstComponents || sameSecondComponents;
    }
```

Finally, create a method which calculates if an arbitary number of points in a list are all between them horizontal or vertical (assuming *if point A is horizontal with point B, then if point C is horizontal with B, so is with A*).

Oveload that method since it does the same thing and the only thing changing are the parameters. (Note the use of the simple *isHorizontal* method from above)

```
   public boolean isHorizontal(List<Point> points){
        boolean allPointsHorizontal = true;
        for (int i=0; i<points.size(); i++) {
            
            boolean nextPointExists = i<points.size() - 1;
            if (nextPointExists) {
                Point current = points.get(i);
                Point next = points.get(i+1);
                allPointsHorizontal = allPointsHorizontal && isHorizontal(current,next);

                if (!allPointsHorizontal)
                    return false;  
            }
        }
        
        return allPointsHorizontal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method could be implemented like this:

```
public boolean isHorizontalOrVertical(Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint, Point thirdPoint) {
    return isHorizontalOrVertical(Arrays.asList(firstPoint, secondPoint, thirdPoint));
}
```

Your `isHorizontalOrVertical(List<Point>)` method will fail when the list is empty, and the call doesn't make much sense when the list has only one element.

I think a better way to do this is with two required parameters, plus a variadic parameter, so that callers must at least give 2 points.

```
private boolean are2PointsHorizontalOrVertical(Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint) {
    return firstPoint.getFirstComponent() == secondPoint.getFirstComponent()
            || firstPoint.getSecondComponent() == secondPoint.getSecondComponent();
}

public boolean arePointsHorizontalOrVertical(Point point1, Point point2, Point... rest) {
    return are2PointsHorizontalOrVertical(point1, point2) &&
        Arrays.stream(rest).allMatch(x -> are2PointsHorizontalOrVertical(point1, x));
}
```

This technically is still "one method" as far as the public interface is concerned. You can substitute the helper `are2PointsHorizontalOrVertical` back into the public method if you *really* want, but I don't see any benefit in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can have only one method:

```
public boolean isHorizontalOrVertical(Point firstPoint, Point secondPoint, Point... others) {
    // check firstPoint, secondPoint for null is ommited
    if (others == null || others.length == 0) {
        return firstPoint.getFirstComponent() == secondPoint.getFirstComponent()
                || firstPoint.getSecondComponent() == secondPoint.getSecondComponent();
    } else {
        // First, create a stream with second point + others elements
        // then match against the first point
        return Stream.of(new Point[]{secondPoint}, others).flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e))
                .allMatch(p -> isHorizontalOrVertical(firstPoint, p));
    }

}
```