# List.of gives error: cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, gradle, compiler-errors

I am using springboot with gradle and I am trying to execute below code in the controller.

```
List<String> planets
    = List.of("Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
    "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune");
```

On compiling I get the following error

> error: cannot find symbol
> = List.of("Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
> ^   symbol:   method of(String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String)
> location: interface List

my gradle file has

> sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

I do understand that its a java 9 feature but unsure why would it fail on compile

Comment: It fails because you set the sourceCompatibility to 1.8...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`List.of` isn't a Java 9 feature, it's a method that was added in JDK 9. If you're using JDK 8, it just doesn't contain this method, and thus can't compile against it.

In short - use a newer JDK (and set the compatibility levels to 9 while you're at it, so you don't create a mix of valid Java 8 program that can only work with a newer JDK).

Comment: I see i am using java 13 in my machine.should List.of work without problem? where else should i be changing the version if i am using intellij on windows machine

Comment: @Hafizallylalani Make sure IntelliJ is really using Java 13 as an SDK; set the language level in the project and set the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` in gradle.

Answer (score 5):

A quick fix is to replace `List.of` with `Arrays.asList` which is in JDK 8.

Note these methods are not quite identical, `List.of` returns an immutable list whereas `Arrays.asList` returns a mutable list. There are a few other differences listed here:

[What is the difference between List.of and Arrays.asList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579074/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-and-arrays-aslist)

Comment: As a possibility, Guava libraries includes an `ImmutableList` class (with `ImmutableList.of` method) if it were needed for an ancient JDK 8-based project.