# How to remove under 18 years old from list?

Tags: java

I  try to remove  all the person  under  18 years old from my list,
so i have a class Person  and   this is what i tried in  my Main:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        Person person1 = new Person("Victor", 28, "meerdonk");
        Person person2 = new Person("Alex", 17, "antwerpen");
        Person person3 = new Person("Vlad", 15, "mechelen");

        List<Person> listOfPersons = List.of(person1, person2, person3);
   
        List<Person> adults = getLessThen18(listOfPersons); **//line 22**
        System.out.println(adults);
}   
 public static List<Person> getLessThen18(List<Person> personList) {

       for (Iterator<Person> iterator = personList.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
           if (iterator.next().getAge() < 18 ) {
                iterator.remove(); **//line 40**
           }
       }
        return personList;
    }
}
```

So I  try to iterate trough the list of persons  and then  if the person is  under 18  to remove it.
As i run the code i get this output :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections.uoe(ImmutableCollections.java:142)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr.remove(ImmutableCollections.java:380)
    at victor.Main.getLessThen18Iteration(Main.java:40)
    at victor.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Can someone please  let me know what I did wrong?

Comment: why not just `return personList.stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() < 18).collect(Collectors.toList());`?

Comment: By the way, when asking a question like "what did I do wrong" you should also tell us how you know there's something wrong (errors, wrong results, etc...)

Comment: And now that I think about it, (minor side note)  isn't the name of the method contradicting the fact that you're *removing* (not getting) people that are younger than 18?

Comment: "Can someone please let me know what I did wrong?" - For we'd need to know how you define "wrong", e.g. what problem you ran into. The `getLessThen18()` method should do the trick with one potential problem: it changes the input list which might not be desired. So you might want to build a new list instead and which case you'd not even need the explicit iterator. Just iterate over the persons and add only those whose age is 18+ to the new list which you return in the end. (What Federico is suggesting in his first comment is basically what I described here.)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ,  you are right  indeed  , it's working  fine.

Regarding error  i sould post also  my  output?
The error i get is

Comment: @BecaliNr1 please [edit] your question. Comments are not good for long outputs or errors.

Comment: Well ... one of the problems is that your `main` method is not declaring and initializing `listOfPersons`.  There may also be problems in your `Person` class, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: @StephenC  , indeed i  forgot to add that here in my  question :( ,

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  , sorry but what do  you mean to  edit my question  ?

Comment: @BecaliNr1 Hit the "[Edit]" button underneath your question (or just the link in this comment) and edit your question to add all the relevant missing information.

Comment: @BecaliNr1 "As i run the code i get the error that" that what? Please edit your question again to complete that sentence.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca   , error  added and lines added to the code where i cet the error .

Comment: Please let this be a good lessen for your next question. As you can see in the given answer, the issue was in the `List.of`, which you added only in the second last edit. Please make sure your question contains a [mcve] when asking future questions about not working code.

Comment: @Ivar
I  will pay  more attention for next time before i post my question :(,  it seems i forrgot to select and copy that line  and  as  given that line was the answer to my question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code (`List.of`) creates an `immutable` list of persons:

```
    List<Person> listOfPersons = List.of(person1, person2, person3);
```

So calling remove/add will cause an Exception - as in your case.

Also your method name is misleading, since you are changing/mutating the passed list parameter and not return a new list (as suggested by the return value).

A possible way to do it would be:

```
 public static List<Person> getLessThen18(List<Person> personList) {
    return personList.stream()
                     .filter(person -> person.getAge() < 18)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());   
 }
```

Comment: Thnk you  ,  that helps   and   output is good  

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the `List.of`. It returns an immutable List, which cannot be modified: [Elements cannot be added, removed, or replaced](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-).

Thus, you get an Exception when you try to call functions such as `iterator.remove();`.

There are these solutions:

- Create a mutable List by copying the elements of the immutable List to a mutable one using a copy constructor:

  `List<Person> listOfPersons = new ArrayList(List.of(person1, person2, person3));`
- Filter the existing List and create a new one (leaving the original List ontouched):

  `return personList.stream().filter(person->person.getAge()<18).collect(Collectors.toList());`

<s>- Create a mutable List right away using `Arrays.asList` (which returns an `ArrayList`)</s>
<s>List listOfPersons = Arrays.asList(person1, person2, person3);`</s>

EDIT: `Arrays.asList` creates an ArrayList, but it's a different class (private static inside of `Arrays`) than anyone would assume..

Comment: Thank you for this ,   this result it's good ,  so i will accept  the one  zho give it first ,

Comment: Please note that Arrays.asList returns a fixed-sized list, so it is not "really" mutable and calling add/remove with it will still fail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579074/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-and-arrays-aslist

Comment: for my  case i  just  replace  :  `List<Person> listOfPersons = List.of(person1, person2, person3);`     with   `List<Person> listOfPersons = new ArrayList(List.of(person1, person2, person3));`

Comment: @HectorLector interesting. I took a look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l3799) and `Arrays.asList` just calls `new ArrayList` internally, so I assumed it was safe to modify. EDIT: confusingly, there is an internal `ArrayList` class inside of `Arrays`, which cannot be modified. I will update the answer.