# Java - How do I create Predicates as Arrays.asList() arguments?

Tags: java, syntax, predicate

I have a few predicates that I want to put in a list so I can then call stream().noneMatch() on my list. I successfully did this by creating named Predicates but how can I create them within an Arrays.asList()'s argument list?

Here's the working code that I'd like to convert:

```java
ArrayList<Predicate<MyClass>> checks = new ArrayList<>();
Predicate<MyClass> isCond1 = myClassHelper::isCond1;
Predicate<MyClass> isCond2 = myClassHelper::isCond2;
checks.add(isCond1);
checks.add(isCond2);
```

I'd expect the result of the conversion to look something like this:

```
List<Predicate> checks = Arrays.asList(myClassHelper::isCond1, myClassHelper::isCond2);
```

or

```
List<Predicate> checks = Arrays.asList(a -> myClassHelper::isCond1, a -> myClassHelper::isCond2);
```

(neither of these are correct)
Where can I specify the argument for the conditions here?

Sorry if this could have been titled better, I always struggle with that.

Comment: What about `List<Predicate<MyClass>> checks = Arrays.asList(a -> myClassHelper.isCond1(a), a -> myClassHelper.isCond2(a));` ?

Comment: @lealceldeiro This appears to work when I explicitly cast `a` to `MyClass`. Would there perhaps be a way to do this while still using the method reference operator(::)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first statement should work but you forgot to specify the predicate type `Predicate<MyClass>`, otherwise the compiler cannot infer it from the method references:

```
List<Predicate<MyClass>> checks2 = Arrays.asList(myClassHelper::isCond1, myClassHelper::isCond2);
```

Or using lambdas:

```
List<Predicate<MyClass>> checks3 = Arrays.asList(a -> myClassHelper.isCond1(a), a -> myClassHelper.isCond2(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert multiple `Predicate` to

#### List

[`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) since JKD 9 is a better API(e.g the return list is immutable, rejecting null), check [What is the difference between List.of and Arrays.asList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579074/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-and-arrays-aslist) for details.

#### Stream

[`Stream.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of(T...)) is even better if you actually want to use Stream API.

#### Predicate

If there are multiple MyClass to test, combining the Predicate to one give your more flexibility, and looks more natural.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MultiplePredicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyClass> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new MyClass(1));
        items.add(new MyClass(2));
        items.add(new MyClass(3));
        //                                          drawback as compiler not smart enough
        Predicate<MyClass> allCondNotMatch = Stream.<Predicate<MyClass>>of(MyClassHelper::isCond1, MyClassHelper::isCond2)
                .map(Predicate::not)
                .reduce((myClass) -> true, Predicate::and);
        List<MyClass> itemsWithAllCondNotMatch = items.stream().filter(allCondNotMatch).toList();
        System.out.println(itemsWithAllCondNotMatch);
    }

    public static class MyClassHelper {
        public static boolean isCond1(MyClass myClass) {
            return myClass.value == 1;
        }

        public static boolean isCond2(MyClass myClass) {
            return myClass.value == 2;
        }
    }

    public static class MyClass {
        private final int value;

        public MyClass(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyClass{" +
                    "value=" + value +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```